# Remove Element from Object Reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use jQuery's `remove()` function to remove an item from the DOM.

The problem is that `remove()` requires a selector and I already have a reference to the element I want to remove in an object.

Given an element reference, say `tableRow`, is there any way to remove that element?

Comment: that should work too

Comment: If `tableRow` is a jquery object then just run remove on it `tableRow.remove()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
tableRow.remove();
```

or

```
$(tableRow).remove();
```

Comment: Ah yes, looking at the jQuery documentation more carefully, I do see that the selector is optional.